# How can I give an index value to a specific date in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, series

I want to assign indicess to the dates in python with respect to a fixed date. For e.g., an index of 1 to 20130101, index of 2 to 20130102 and so on upto 20181231. These dates are in a python dataframe. The indices could be overwritten on the dates in the dataframe. Could someone please suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subtract `date` objects. That gives a timedelta that's easily converted to the number of days. From your explanation this sounds exactly like what you're looking for:

```
>>> (datetime.date(2013, 1, 2)-datetime.date(2013, 1, 1)).days
1
>>> (datetime.date(2013, 1, 31)-datetime.date(2013, 1, 1)).days
30
```

Here, the right-hand-side argument is the fixed date you're anchoring to.

Comment: This is helpful. Since the date ranges from 20130101 to 20181231, could you also tell me how to loop through the dates?

Comment: This is a good answer in pure Python, but doesn't take advantage of Pandas / NumPy vectorised functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`pandas.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) in a dict comprehension to create a `pandas.Series` object with your desired index and value:

```
start_date = '20130101'
end_date = '20181231'

date_idx = pd.Series({d:i+1 for i, d in enumerate(pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='D'))})
```

Which looks like:

```
2013-01-01       1
2013-01-02       2
2013-01-03       3
2013-01-04       4
2013-01-05       5
2013-01-06       6
...
2018-12-26    2186
2018-12-27    2187
2018-12-28    2188
2018-12-29    2189
2018-12-30    2190
2018-12-31    2191
```

You can then map this to any `datetime` column in a `pandas.DataFrame` using [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html). For example:

```
df['date_idx'] = df['date_column'].map(date_idx)
```

Answer (score 1):

No explicit loop is required here. You can use [`pd.Series.dt.days`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': pd.date_range('2013-01-01', '2018-12-31', freq='D')})

df['index'] = (df['dates'] - df['dates'].iat[0]).dt.days + 1

print(df)

          dates  index
0    2013-01-01      1
1    2013-01-02      2
2    2013-01-03      3
3    2013-01-04      4
4    2013-01-05      5
...         ...    ...
2186 2018-12-27   2187
2187 2018-12-28   2188
2188 2018-12-29   2189
2189 2018-12-30   2190
2190 2018-12-31   2191
```